# How to implement `analogRead` (Arduino) on AVR?

Tags: arduino, analog, adc, avr, c++

I'm trying to implement `Pin` class in C++ with `digitalRead`, `digitalWrite`, `analogRead` and `analogWrite` methods like in `Arduino` SDK.
I know how to read analog signals using the ADC input number (not port&pin number).
But in my class, I know only about port and pin and I want to check if this pin is supported ADC and if it is, I want to get the ADC channel number. How can I do it?

[image: ATmega328P pinout]

For example, I have only PORT C and pin 5, and I need to get 5 ADC channel number.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Surely you can simply convert from input set of your port and pin definitions to output set of ADC channel, you can use dozens of if statements, switch/case or lookup table or any method you like. It has nothing to do with electronics though, this is a pure programming question. Do note that port pin number matches ADC channel number so you only need to check if you are given C port and pin is below 6.

Comment: Just look at the picture and try and figure it yourself.

Comment: You can set up a look-up table using information from the 328P datasheet and/or the Arduino library code. It's how I did it for my SAMD21G PWM library, so look-up table example [here](https://github.com/ocrdu/Arduino_SAMD21_turbo_PWM/blob/master/src/SAMD21turboPWM.h).

Comment: @Justme, oh, I know, but I want to implement it universally, for every AVR microcontroller, using the preprocessor, maybe `io.h` somehow can help me to do it? Maybe I will use a table with information about the pin, ADC support, ADC number, etc, but I need to get this information every compilation time, in depend on a microcontroller to compile a program to.

Comment: @manueld4722623 there's no way to know it except knowing it. The Arduino libraries just have a table containing that information for each board they support. If you're not using them, then you have to do the same thing yourself.

Comment: There is no such mapping anywhere to know which analog pin matches which digital pin. Nice idea, but it will be a huge job to write and maintain such tables universally for every AVR MCU. And some AVRs have pins that are analog only, so you can't find ADC6 if you search based on digital pin.

Comment: You can check everything at compile time. I have implemented something similar (but very different) to `digitalRead/Write`. You can check my implementation [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/avr_pin.h). And [here](https://github.com/amanuellperez/mcu/blob/master/src/avr/test/pin/main.cpp) you can see a basic example of how to use it. You can find an ADC implementation also but that, I think, is very different from Arduino.